# My imported 3d model is weirdly textured with transparent and depth issues making it look bizarre even when rendered

Tags: import, transparency, error, obj

[image: A pic of the wierd effect you can see inside the house the windows are black and the back walls are viewable from the front angle. Also the light post on the right is basically invidslbe.]

I just imported this wooden house OBJ from a free 3d model website, turbosquid I believe. It came with textures but was originally a hot pink color so I have to use the "find missing textures" option and went to the texture folder. After textures were applied through this method, this is how it came out. It's weird and like transparent and clearly has some depth issues as the back walls are seeable in the photos and the lightpost is basically invisible for no reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Change the blend method on the materials to "Alpha Hashed". Or use Cycles.